# Making an image responsive in a slider

Tags: css, image

My first slide on this page, Promotion slide wasn't responsive...I added

```
      max-width: 100%; height: auto
```

to the css. It works But now it adds too much space below the image when viewing on mobile device. It also makes the title disappear. How do I make this image responsive, but get rid of the space below?

http://new.921thefrog.com/index.php/test-promo-slider/

Here is the rest of the code

```
      .promo_slider_wrapper { margin:10px 0; position:relative; }
    .promo_slider { height:235px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
     .promo_slider img {margin:0; padding:0; max-width: 100%; height: auto }
   promo_slider .panel {
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to center the image you can apply this on the img elements:

```
img {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;

}
```

But still you will need some js if H > W because in that case the height should be 100% and the width auto

// EDIT

I just took a look at the page source code

```
<div class="promo_slider auto_advance" style=" height:418px;">
```

the height should be set to auto, not 418px

Comment: that 418px and that whole line automatically shows when i enter the shortcode

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "shortcode" but that line is the probl for sure, try to override it, maybe add some media queries ? idk really, that should be auto

Comment: I am using WordPress so when I enter the shortcode onto the page, I think that is just picking up what size my images are